# VB: Repeat the function evey x minutes?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with visual basic express 2010 to create a very simple application.

I know this is basic stuff but i need to know how to repeat the same function every X minute while the application is being left open.

This is all my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
"http://google.co.uk/images/someimage.png", "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/someimage.png")

    End Sub

End Class
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

EDIT:

This is my entire code now:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
"http://new.tse.ir/en/json/MarketWatch/enMarketWatch_1.xls", "C:/temp/enMarketWatch_1.xls", "", "", False, 60, True)

    End Sub
End Class
```

in the properties panel of the timer, I set the Enabled to true and Interval to 60000.

when i run this code, I get file downloaded but 1 second later, the file gets deleted automatically and an error pops up in the visual basic saying `the operation has timed out`

I tried to change the directory and still happening.

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: @Plutonix, i honestly have no idea how to use timer. any chance you could advise me on that?

Comment: [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx)  google is your friend, seriously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a timer to your form in the graphical designer.

Double click the timer to generate its tick event handler code in the code window.

Move the code you want to repeat into a sub

```
Private Sub DownloadFile()
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://google.co.uk/images/someimage.png", "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/someimage.png")
End Sub
```

Add the command below  into your timer tick event handler

```
DownloadFile()
```

Change your form.load event to

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DownloadFile()
    Timer1.Interval = x ' where x is the number of minutes*60000 because there are 60000 ticks in a minute
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

The reason I've put your code into a separate sub is so that it is easily  reusable in both the form.load handler and the timer.tick handler without having to write it again, and if in the future you need to change, for example the file path, you only need to remember to change it once.

Also I should add that, in the form.load handler I have included the `DownloadFile` method because, when the timer is enabled, it won't generate a tick until the interval has elapsed. Not at the beginning when the timer is enabled.

Also - as Plutonix suggested in comments below - If it is possible that the file to be downloaded will take longer to download than the length of the timer interval you should disable the timer in the `DownloadFile` sub and enable it again at the end of the sub. Like so :-

```
Private Sub DownloadFile()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://google.co.uk/images/someimage.png", "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/someimage.png")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't have a timer in the graphical designer. its because I'm using express version.

Comment: !! They don't include a timer?? Wow! That's tight. I would suggest (If possible ) that you download the VS 2015 community edittion.

Comment: Yes they do (or at least VB Express 2010 does). Look around in the Tool Box @rooz.

Comment: @VisualVincent, i swear I don't see it at all. I don't have it!!

Comment: Not knowing how large the files are or if they are really just an image, I would disable the Timer while/when it is downloading and re-enable it afterwards.  Might not matter *here* but future visitors might need that kind of safeguard.  +1

Comment: @Plutonix Added to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I followed your answer and finally its working. now I got another issue though! I'm keep getting Could not complete operation since a file already exists in this path. so i tried to overwrite the existing file by Nothing, Nothing, 1000, True and still I get an error! any idea?

Comment: A quick look through intellisense for `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile` showed alternative parameters. Try this - tho I don't know if it will work.  `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://google.co.uk/images/someimage.png", "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/someimage.png","","",False,60,True)`. The extra parameters are `username,password,ShowUI,timeout,overwrite`.  I dont know if it will work with a blank username and password, but it's worth a go.

Comment: In part the suggestion was for what you now face: unique files.  The OP probably may not want to overwrite the files (otherwise, why a timer?), so you may need to concoct some sort of `...image001` scheme.  At which point, you dont want 2 ticks trying to write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: @rooz - do you want to overwrite the file if it already exists or to rename either the earlier download or the new download?

Comment: @DavidWilson, I want to overwrite it if it exist.

Comment: ah ok. does my last comment work with blank passwords etc?

Comment: I haven't tested it mainly because I didn't need to. the file is not too large at all.

Comment: I mean the code in my comments about overwriting the original :)

Comment: `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://google.co.uk/images/someimage.png", "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/someimage.png","","",False,60,True)`. The extra parameters are username,password,ShowUI,timeout,overwrite

Comment: ah yes, I tried that. strange things happening when i use that code. It will download the file and puts it on my desktop BUT 1 second later it will delete it and my code in visual basic gets highlighted (yellow colour) and a window pops up saying "The operation has timed out" !

Comment: Hmm. That might be something to do with local file permissions. Have you tried downloading it to another directory - say C:\Temp.

Comment: Yes, tried that as well and the same thing happens with the same error "The operation has timed out"

Comment: this worked like a charm: "", "", False, 100000, True

Comment: Excellent! Glad everything got there eventually.